# show a hidden element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know why it doesn't work with ***bootstrap modal***.

I want to show the hidden element.

I tried 3 different way's

(with
 **display:none;** and in javascript a did **$('..').show()**,

**visibility:hidden** and in the javascript **$('..').css('visibilty','visible')**,

and the **class="hidden"** and in the javascript **$('..').removeClass('hidden')**)

here is my code :

```js
$('.btn[id="zaki"]').click(function() {
  $('#show_1524').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="zaki">ilyes_show</button>
<div>
  <p style="display:none;" id="show_1524">..................</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Added jQuery to your snippet.  Works fine

Comment: jquery works fine.

Comment: So... since it works, what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your code works fine but since inline styles have highest specificity replace the inline style with a class and then on button click use `removeClass` to remove it

```js
$('.btn[id="zaki"]').click(function() {
  $('#show_1524').removeClass('hideElem');
})
```

```css
.hideElem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="zaki">ilyes_show</button>
<div>
  <p class="hideElem" id="show_1524">..................</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn[id="zaki"]').click(function() {
  $('#show_1524').show();
})

$('.btn[id="zaki-hide"]').click(function() {
  $('#show_1524').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="zaki">ilyes_show</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="zaki-hide">ilyes_hide</button>
<div>
  <p style="display:none;" id="show_1524">..................</p>
</div>
```